# formatted="false" for Quantity Strings (Plurals)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm using a quantity string and eclipse tells me:

```
    error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the 
 formatted="false" attribute?
```

But adding `formatted="false"` to the `plurals` or `item` tag doesn't solve the problem. Eclipse still comes up with the same error.

Here an example xml code which produces the error:

```
    <plurals name="time">
        <item quantity="other">time: %02d:%02d</item>
    </plurals>
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 5):

Just saw this question. For others who are looking for it, use it like this:

```
    <plurals name="time">
      <item quantity="other">time: %01$02d:%02$02d</item>
    </plurals>
```

- `%01` -> is denotes the 1st variable, `%02` -> denotes the 2nd
- `$02d` -> defines decimal formatting

Comment: Can you explain what it means?

Comment: Let me break into like this 1) %01$02d- 01 defines the first variable for decimal  substitution and 02 is the formatting. 
Similarly, 2) %01$02d - 02 defines the first variable for decimal  substitution and 02 is the formatting.
Technically it should be other way around, but it doesn't work like that...